# counter in if statement

Tags: if-statement, scheme

I prepared a few lines in Scheme and I am new to Scheme. Please post your comments about my code below:

```
(define new3 
  (lambda(y)
(define points 444)
(define add3 (lambda (x)(+ x 3)))
  (display "--")
    (display points)

(if (and (= 1 1)(= 2 2))(add3 points))   

  (display "--")
    (display points)

  (list points points)
))


(new3 7)
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
--444--444(444 444)
```

I wonder why the "points" after the "if" are not equal to "447"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you didn't update `points` in-place. You computed `477` with `(add3 points)`, but without storing that result anywhere.

Comment: Please suggest how I can store the result points = points + 3. In which place? Under the "if"?
Many thanks.

Comment: You can replace the useless `if` by `(setq points (add3 points))`.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I need the "if" stuff since I have a condition to be verified (not only (= 1 1)). In other words, I want to check a condition, and if it holds modify points.

Comment: @Debbie: Then simply replace the `(add3 points)` with `(set! points (add3 points))`.